# Django app works locally but deployment on GCP say 500 Server Error, "ImportError: Could not import settings"

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, web-deployment

On GCP dashboard I get this error but on my machine all works fine:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'site.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings
at __init__ (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/conf/__init__.py:95)
at _setup (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/conf/__init__.py:42)
at __setattr__ (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/functional.py:207)
at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/g~unitutor-221411/1.413727868439486493/main.py:9)
at LoadObject (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:85)
at _LoadHandler (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:299)
at Handle (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/3b44e98ed7fbb86b/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:240)
```

This is my app.yaml:

```
application: *********
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.4"
- name: jinja2
  version: "latest"
```

Obviously I have, locally and on GCP, a directory "site" containing "settings.py". On my machine the app works well. I tried in many ways and I read many posts but I can't find a solution to solve the "500 Server Error" on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Local and production are two different things. You are getting this error because your paths are incorrectly handled in GCP. Try to check where it is looking for settings.py file and then reconfigure it.